# Camera view is broken

Tags: 3d-view, camera

Camera placed like this (settings can be found at right):
[image]

If I enter camera view, I see this:
[image]

If enable viewport render it shows ok:
[image]

Also render from this camera is also proper

Why is this happening to camera view in any other mode?

UPD

[image]

UPD2

video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OV24sDP3spg&feature=youtu.be

Comment: probably camera/view  clipping issue...

Comment: It would be useful to those who might want to help you solve your problem and to those who might chance upon a similar problem in the future, if you would upload the ~.blend file to [Blend-Exchange](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) and edit a link to the uploaded file into your question.

Comment: Can you see anything in the render mode?

Comment: @brasshat added

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue you are having with the file you uploaded. If I press Numpad 0 I get this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/psEFx.png What are  your system's specs?

Comment: @cegaton very strange... system: mac os 10.12.4, blender 2.78c

Comment: AMD GPU part of the system?

Comment: @cegaton yes, radeon pro 460 4gigs

Comment: added video screencast to post

Comment: I have experienced weird issues with opebGL in 3d view before. Try setting the camera clip manually, by zooming a long way out and using Alt B to define clipping region. Make sure to include the camera and other geometry.

Comment: Not really sure what is causing this issue. (I'm not able to reproduce this) However it should be fixed when you upgrade from 2.78 to 2.79.

Answer (score 1):

We experienced the same issue here, though in our case the Viewport Render would not work either any more. However, we found out that it is linked to the Blender Screen Area, not the camera. We noticed this because we actually had more than one 3D View in our layout, and only one of them would show the described behavior. We checked again and again, and all properties were set correctly. They were indeed identical across the areas.

To fix it, switch another screen area to a 3D View. The camera should behave as it is supposed to there. Now collapse the broken one. You can also switch to a different screen layout using the Dropdown box in the header:

[image: Screen Layout]

Comment: Wow, thanks for this. I had "Lock Camera to View" active to navigate camera view but it was scaling the camera and its origin way way up. I killed the window and used another one. All went back to normal. So I guess its a screen space issue?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of only pressing <kbd>Numpad 0</kbd>, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Numpad 0</kbd> with camera selected and it will set it as active.

Then it should display the correct facing orientation.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things I noticed. Although I could see the objects in camera view, these things were present when I was testing your blend file and it could be the solution to the problem.

Under Camera.001 Selected > Properties Panel > Object Data > Clipping, your clipping distance is too small at 1 micrometer. It cause artifacts when viewed through the camera changed it to 1mm and it was fixed.

Your camera is really big but I *doubt* that could be the issue since it works fine regardless of size - but **it could be the issue**, so it wouldn't hurt to scale it down to what I have here:
[image: Scale Camera]

Tested On: Windows 10, Version: 2.79

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same trouble, what I was modelling was ridiculously out of scale. (Lego brick 5m long). I edited the end clipping distance (went up to 60m) and the problem was solved.

Answer (score -3):

I don't now whats happening,  but I'm pretty sure that you can fix it by deleting the existing camera and replacing it with a new one.

Comment: Rather than deleting the existing camera and replacing it with a new one, I'd add a second camera, in the same position, and if there is a difference between the views of the two cameras, begin changing any parameters in the second camera one by one, so that they match the different parameters of the first, and see where the problem lies. This is a technique I've used in the past.