# Camera behavior ..broken?

Tags: camera

I've got something weird. I added a third camera to my scene and all of a sudden, when i press '0' to shift the view to the camera, i get a weird view on my scene, and io am not able to change it (f.e. i cannot zoom or rotate the view when i have 'Lock Camera to view' unchecked). When i do check 'Lock camera to view', and i try to change the position, i get very weird clipping and behavior.

I was using the 2.79 RC2 release. But the problem persists when opening the scene with 2.78.

[image: Position of the camera]

[image: Weird clipping]

Anyone know what could be the problem? Maybe i pressed some buttom unknowingly?

Thnx anyway, Casper.

Comment: What device are you using as render device in Blender? Did you try checking CPU in User prefs? It could be a bug in graphic drivers as it isn't experienced for all users downloading that file.

Comment: I was using GPU, i tried setting it to CPU to see if there was any difference, but none whatsoever. Anyway, it's a good tip to always check if a problem persists on CPU, so thnx!

Answer (score 1):

I have a solution, but i still do not know what caused this problem.

When i create an extra Screen Layout (opened the '3D view Full' and pressed the '+' to make it a new one, named it 'Default_2'), and reconstructed my preferred screenview, the problem is gone. The original Default screenview is still broken. Dunno why.

Found this solution in another topic:

[Original posted solution to the same problem](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/79667/camera-view-is-broken?rq=1)

Comment: check the clip distance for the viewport and the camera read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8553/why-does-part-of-my-model-disappear-when-i-zoom-in-on-it-in-the-3d-viewport/8554#8554

Comment: Yes, i tried to edit these values (made them equal to each other) but nothing happened, whatever i did with these settings.

Answer (score 0):

When you enter camera view, does it actually fly into the camera like it's supposed to, or does it fly into some other object?

There's a keyboard shortcut (<kbd>⌃ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Num 0</kbd>) that will make the viewport treat another object like a camera. To undo that, select the camera and either press <kbd>⌃ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Num 0</kbd> or go to View > Cameras > Set Active Object as Camera.

**Edit:** Apparently this isn't your problem, but I'll leave this answer here in case it helps someone else.

Comment: That happens often but it's visible on the first screenshot that in the Properties editor > Scene tab > Scene rollout Camera object is set as active camera.